# Java Calendar isn't showing correct HOUR_OF_DAY

Tags: java, calendar, java.util.calendar, java-calendar

I am using the Calendar class in java and am having trouble. I have this code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("NZST"));
System.out.println("Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY = " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("Calendar.HOUR = " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println("calendar.getTime() = " + calendar.getTime());
```

and I would expect it to output

```
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY = 17
Calendar.HOUR = 5
calendar.getTime() = Sat Aug 08 17:45:53 NZST 2020
```

but instead it outputs

```
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY = 5
Calendar.HOUR = 5
calendar.getTime() = Sat Aug 08 17:45:53 NZST 2020
```

So why does the HOUR_OF_DAY and HOUR return the same thing however, calendar.getTime() shows the correct HOUR_OF_DAY. They are both using NZST.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312411/5772882).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They are both using NZST.

No, they're not, although I can see why you think they are.

The first is *actually* using UTC, because "NZST" is not a valid time zone ID. It's a shame that `TimeZone.getTimeZone` doesn't throw an exception when you present it with an invalid ID, but that can't be changed now :(

`calendar.getTime()` is returning a `Date` reference, and [`Date` doesn't have a time zone](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) so it's printing in your system local time zone - which happens to be New Zealand.

If you change your first line of code to use a *real* time zone ID, it behaves as you expect it to:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
```

A *few* abbreviations (like NZST) are recognized as time zone IDs in Java, but it's *always* better to use the full [IANA time zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) ID, like "Pacific/Auckland".

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
) 
.getHour()
```

## Details

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312290/642706) is correct. In addition, you are using terrible classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class in *java.time* replaces the [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) class `TimeZone`. This class `ZoneId` fulfills the wish in Jon Skeet’s Answer: If you feed it a false zone ID like `NZST`, it throws an exception.

## *java.time*

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;  // Specify a time zone. A history of past, present, and future changes to the offset-from-UTC used by the people of a particular region. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current time as seen in a particular time zone.
int hour = zdt.getHour() ;                    // Extract the hour of he day.
```